# Help with x11 and dev.off

Tags: r

Why does this code throw warnings & how should I rewrite it?

```
x11(width = 8, height = 8)
plot(1:10)
points(1, 5, col='red')
dev.off()  # Throws "Warning message: In dev.off() : Display list redraw incomplete"
```

The error disappears if I remove the x11() line.  Thank you in advance,

Adrian

Comment: I cannot replicate this. On my Linux system, the first three commands do what you'd expect them to; and the last simply closes the graphics windows opened by the earlier `x11()` with the dimensions you had given.

Comment: No reproduce on R 2.12.2 on Windows 7, 64 bit.

Comment: Works on R 2.12.1 Win XP 32 bit.    Type in sessionInfo() and what do you get?

Comment: See my answer below. What are you trying to achieve, anyway?

Comment: Why are you using `x11()` and not `dev.new()`?

Comment: @hadley, I can replicate the bug with `dev.new` also. If I pass `height` and `width` parameters, I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this bug, but only if I'm trying to `source` the code. I get two empty plot windows. You may have noticed that at first there's 8x8 X11 window, but then it's closed, and you end up with two default-sized windows (7x7), with the one in the front marked as ACTIVE. However, if you omit `width` and `height` parameters, everything works OK. This looks like X11 issue to me, and, frankly, I have no bloody idea what causes it, but it definitely has something to do with device geometry. If I set `X11.options(width = 8, height = 8)` and `source` the script, I get the same bug again.

Long story short, I can replicate the bug, but I have no idea what's causing it. Anyway, this yields no errors:

```
x11()
plot(1:10)
points(1, 5, col='red')
dev.off()
```

---

**EDIT**

I'm using Arch Linux FWIW, here's my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C              LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```